# On a relation between volume of subsets of $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, volume

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let for all Lebesgue measurable subsets $A,B$ of $\mathbb R^n$ , ${v(A+B)}^r \geq {v(A)}^p + {v(B)}^q$ for some $0\leq p,q,r \leq 1$ where $v(X)$ is volume of $X$(which equals the Lebesgue measure of $X).$
Show $p+q=r.$

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$I tried to use dilation(by $\delta >0$) of the sets $A,B,C.$
Then,${v(\delta(X))}={\delta}^n.v(X).$
And, $\delta(A+B)=\delta(A)+\delta(B).$

But, I couldn't approach further .

A hint is required, thanks in advance .

Comment: Is the $’+’$ referring to the Minkowski sum?

Comment: The usual sum of two subsets of $\mathbb R^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. In fact, you must have $p=q=r$ and $r \geqslant \frac 1 n$, see [the Brunn-Minkowski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brunn%E2%80%93Minkowski_theorem). (I feel like you must also have $r \leqslant \frac 1 n$ but I haven't though of a way to prove this). This all comes down to rescaling. Let $B_R$ denote a ball with radius $R>0$. I split the proof into several parts. For simplicity, I will also only deal with the case $p,q,r>0$ - with a suitable modification of the proofs below you should be able to obtain the same result.

---

Proof that $p=q=r$: It is an easy exercise to prove that $B_{R_1}+B_{R_2} = B_{R_1+R_2}$. Choose $R$ such that $\nu (B_R)=1$. Then for all $s,t>0$,\begin{align*}
(s+t)^{nr}&= \nu (B_{(s+t)R})^r \\
&\geqslant \nu (B_{sR})^p + \nu (B_{tR})^q \\
&=s^{np} + t^{nq}.\tag{$\ast$}
\end{align*} Sending $s \to 0^+$, in $(\ast)$ we obtain $$ t^{nr} \geqslant t^{nq} \qquad \text{ for all } t>0.$$ This is only true if $q=r$. Similarly, we may send $t\to 0^+$ in $(\ast)$ to obtain $p=r$.

---

Proof that $r \geqslant \frac 1 n$: Setting $s=\delta t$, $\delta>0$ in $(\ast)$ and, using that $p=q=r$, we obtain $$(1+\delta)^{nr} \geqslant \delta^{nr} +1 \qquad \text{ for all } \delta>0.$$ This is true if and only if $nr \geqslant 1$.